# Include a Cmf Blog on a page

Tags: symfony-cmf

In my application I want to do a page with:

1. A CMF blog
2. Other elements like a list of FosUser

To include CMF blog bundle in my template I tried:

```
{{ render(controller('CmfBlogBundle:Blog:list', { 'id': 'public-blog' })) }}
```

where "public-blog" is the ID of the blog.

Of course, that's not work :(

Can anyone help me to do that? Sorry in advance if it's a really basic task :/

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found the solution inside twig:

```
{{ render(url('/cms/routes/blog/public-blog')) }}
```